# When does the power series converge?

Tags: complex-analysis

For what values of $z\in \mathbb{C}$ does 
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left( \frac{z}{z+1}\right)^n $$ converge?

Edit: I tried looking at the function $f(z)=1/(z+1)$ to see what values of $z$ might be mapped such that the series converges, but it seemed confusing since I don’t know much complex analysis at this point.

Comment: Just a remark, this is not strictly speaking a power series (of the form $\sum a_nz^n$) so we can expect to find a region of the plane which is not necessarily a disk.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**

Recall that $f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty z^n$ converges if and only if $|z| < 1$. Can you use this to characterize the convergence of your series?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $\require{cancel}\;|z|^2 \lt |z+1|^2 \iff z\bar z \lt (z+1)(\bar z +1) = z \bar z + z + \bar z + 1 \iff z+ \bar z \gt -1\,$.

Comment: So it converges on the plane to the right of Re$(z)=-1/2$?

Comment: @Garou That's correct.